# Keyboard shortcut for "Show Desktop"

Tags: macos

What is the OS X equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> for Linux or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> for Windows to show the desktop.

Tried to search but didn't get some feasible answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The <kbd>F11</kbd> key shows the desktop by default.

If you would like to change it, you can in the keyboard preference pane under keyboard shortcuts, Mission Control. Feel free to make it <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>

Be aware that the function keys normally map to volume control / brightness, so you have to hold the <kbd>fn</kbd> key down to get <kbd>F11</kbd> to be <kbd>F11</kbd> instead of  *(the best I can do for the volume down icon that coexists on the key labeled F11.)*